# avoid repeatedly writing model formula when fitting a number of linear regression models

Tags: r, regression, formula, linear-regression, lm

I'd like to run a number of similar linear regression models in R, such as

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = df)
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, data = df)
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7, data = df)
```

How can I assign part of this to a "base" formula, to avoid repeating it many times? This would be the base:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
```

Then how can I do something like the following (obviously not working)?

```
lm(base + x6, data = df)
```

Searching on Stack Overflow I realized that I could make a data frame with only variables of interest and use `.` to shorten the model formula, but I wonder if this could be avoided.

Comment: You might find `step` useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update a model formula with `update.formula`. For example:

```
base <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
update.formula(base, . ~ . + x6)
#y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6
```

Here is a strings version if you want to provide new variable name as character:

```
## `deparse` damp a model formula to a string
formula(paste(deparse(base), "x6", sep = " + "))
```

In fact, you can even update your model directly

```
fit <- lm(base, dat); update.default(fit, . ~ . + x6)
```

---

> This idea that updates the whole model worked the best. Only `update()` was needed in my case.

I wrote `update.default` and `update.formula` so that you know what function to look for when you do `?` for the documentation.